# React - Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am following a React video course. I've entered in the code exactly as it appears on the screen. It's working in the video, but not for me.

Here is the code:

```
 <Link to={'/product/${props.id}'}><button>Product Details</button></Link>
```

Comment: It's exactly the problem the error tells you about... [Read the fine manual.](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-template-curly-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use a template literal within single quotes.
In JavaScript, template literals are enclosed in backticks (`), not single quotes (').

```
<Link to={`/product/${props.id}`}>
```